# Copy of a list (or something else) in Scheme

Tags: list, copy, scheme, racket

I'm newbie in Scheme and find out that if I change a list with set-car!/set-cdr! (even locally) the parent list is modified too. This is an example what I mean:

```
(define my-list '(1 2 3 4 5)) ; Original list

(define (function list) ; Some example function
   (let ((copy list))
        (set-car! copy 'new)
   (display copy)
)

(function my-list); will display (new 2 3 4 5)

my-list; but the original is changed "forever" and will be also '(new 2 3 4 5)
```

**My question is:**
Is there a way to make a copy of the original list and work only on it, so at the end the original not to be changed?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your code `(let ((copy list))` allows list to be accessed through the name copy. So when you `set-car!` copy, you are actually `set-car!`'ing the original list.

The phenomenon of mutation in lisp  like languages is a little confusing at first.

Mutation is to be avoided usually, for the reasons you have discovered. Parts of lists and things a floating around. This is because internally each node in a list has two parts - the `car` is it's value which may point to another list, and it's `cdr` is the part that follows it - usually this is a lit of things similar to the value in `car`.

This solves your problem using SRFI1's list-copy function
    (let ((copy (list-copy list)))

Here is one way to copy a list (make a new list). This code is not really complete. When we look at it internally it adds pieces of a list in each recursive call. Where do the pieces of each new list-section come from? The `cdr` is generated with the call `(list-copy (cdr list))`, while the `car` is simply taken - not copied! - from the other list.

```
(define (list-copy list)
  (if (null? list) '() (cons (car list) (list-copy (cdr list)))))
```

The result for you when experimenting, was that the car's of your list `copy` where borrowed from `my-list`.

Here is a more proper version:

```
(define (full-copy list)
(if (null? list) 
  '() 
  (if (list? list) 
      (cons (full-copy (car list)) (full-copy (cdr list)))
      list)))
```

Only the code for the `car` has changed. Now, the car is reconstructed to. The only parts that are borrowed are the numbers (so this copy is not okay when the numbers are instead something more special). I'm not sure how the srfi1 version works.

The let statement only ever binds one identifier to an object - the object is not copied, you simply have another way to access it. So any changes (use of mutation, as in functions that end in "!") will affect both.

Comment: 1) list-copy is not defined in scheme; 2) I know how to make a function that copy list but when I use set-car! for example all changes made to the copy will transfer to the original. Any ideas?

Comment: ops, I'm wrong. With a copy function works great. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: SRFI-1 has `list-copy`.

Comment: Ok, I have last question (based on this) - Can somebody explain me why when I use 'assoc', the original is also affected? Example here - http://repl.it/NUv/1

Comment: @NoSense my copy (and maybe list-copy, for all I know) did not copy the pairs, only the structure around them.

Comment: Your comment about that the list-copy didn't copy the pairs was plenty enough to understand the problem and to try writing it myself :D. Thanks again!

Comment: Much simpler version: `(define (list-copy l) (apply list l))`.

Comment: @larsmans thanks, the example was designed to be transparent though, not the correct way - though i wonder what is the best simplest recursive copy? (i'm no schemer)

Comment: That would be the first version you posted.

Comment: @larsmans the first one doesn't copy the lists properly (it copies the lists but not the lists in the lists, etc) - this is what i mean `(define (list-copy l) (if (list? l) (map list-copy l) l))`

Comment: @user3125280 It is a proper list copy. It's just not a tree copy.

Comment: @larsmans then what is the simplest tree copy? (other than tree-copy)

Comment: @user3125280 Depends on how you define a tree :) If trees are built out of proper lists and items are anything but lists, then what you've just posted is the simplest version. If trees are cons cells (pairs), then that's `(define (tree-copy t) (if (pair? t) (cons (tree-copy (car t)) (tree-copy (cdr t))) t))`.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest that when you're learning Scheme or Racket, you avoid all the `!` functions such as `set-car!`, `set-cdr!`, and `set!`.

Instead of mutating things, try to think in terms of creating a new thing from the old thing(s).

For instance if you have a list and want something new at the start:

```
;; Return a new list with `x` replacing the head of the list `xs`.
(define (replace-head xs x) ; list? any? -> list?
  (cons x (cdr xs)))

;; Using it:
(replace-head '(1 2 3 4 5) 100)
; => '(100 2 3 4 5)
```

p.s. A version of `replace-head` that can handle `xs` being empty could be:

```
(define (replace-head xs x) ; list? any? -> list?
  (cond [(empty? xs) (list x)]
        [else        (cons x (cdr xs))]))

(replace-head '(1 2 3 4 5) 100)
; => '(100 2 3 4 5)
(replace-head '() 100)
; => '(100)
```

You also might find it helpful to look at [How to Design Programs](http://htdp.org/), for examples of good ways to design and think in Scheme or Racket.

Comment: Just to clarify, in Racket cons cells are immutable and there is no `set-car!`. Mutable cons cells must be explicitly created with `mcons` and mutation occurs with `set-mcar!` and `set-mcdr`. Use of mutable lists "is strongly discouraged" but is possible using `mlist` from the `compatiblity/mlist` module. http://docs.racket-lang.org/compatibility/mlists.html?q=mlist#%28def._%28%28lib._compatibility%2Fmlist..rkt%29._mlist%29%29

Comment: Just to clarify more, racket != scheme. Specifically, mutability is very common and accepted in scheme (racket goes to lengths to avoid it). Everyone who is keen to upvote an answer this sensible should remember no one sensible codes really big/important things in scheme. Not that it isn't a good point.

Comment: To clarify^3, I said "when learning". If I come from an imperative language and I over-use `set!` -- then I won't learn well. After learning: Of course mutation isn't always bad; neither Scheme nor Racket take the stance of Haskell. So when people code big/important things, and _very wisely_ choose Racket or Scheme to do so, they might judiciously use some mutation.